# Sending Images over tcp on android(local network)

Tags: android, image, tcp, wifi

I have been trying to write an app that sends images to another android device for a while now and I'm failing. I get nothing on the server side. Below is my client code, may you please help me figure out where I am going wrong.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class ClientLate extends Activity {


    private static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    ImageView imageView;
    Button send;
    Bitmap bmp;
    private Socket socket;
    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ImageView img;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.111.11";
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_late);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSend);


        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public void onBrowseClick(View v) {

        Button imagePick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBrowse);
                //pick image from the gallery
                //Intent picPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);


                //start an activity and tell it we want a result
                //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                //tvServerMsg.setText(String.valueOf(imageUpload.getTag()));

    }


        public  void onSend(View view) {

                        //ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                        //Bitmap btmp = Bitmap.create(imageView.getBitmap());
                        //imageView2.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
                        byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();

                    try {
                        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
                        dos.writeInt(array.length);
                        dos.write(array, 0, array.length);

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        System.out.printf("Problem 1");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.printf("Problem 2");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.printf("Problem 3");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }




    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                TextView path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPath);
                path.setText("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public void selectPic(View view) {
        try {

            //EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            //String str = et.getText().toString();
            Button bBrowse = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bBrowse));
            bBrowse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                }
            });


            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
            byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();

            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
            dos.writeInt(array.length);
            dos.write(array, 0, array.length);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder().setName("ClientLate Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]")).build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW).setObject(object).setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }


    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket("192.168.111.11", 8080);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

The Manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.melo.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ClientLate">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_client_late"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.melo.myapplication.ClientLate">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bBrowse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Browse"
            android:onClick="onBrowseClick"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send"
            android:onClick="onSend"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPath"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Log.

```
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 757K, 14% free 14096K/16387K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err:     at com.example.melo.myapplication.ClientLate.onSend(ClientLate.java:104)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3598)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4103)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17117)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you actually debugged this? There's a variable somewhere within `ClientLate.onSend` method that has tripped up null pointer exception, uninitialized perhaps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

try to change

> `OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
>                           DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
>                           dos.writeInt(array.length);
>                           dos.write(array, 0, array.length);`

to:

> `OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
>      output.write(array, 0, array.length);;
>      output.flush();`